# How to enable reporting for all objects?

Tags: administration

What is the easiest way to tick the `Enable Reports` checkbox for all my 100+ objects? Is there any tool available to do this or should I edit all objects manually in `Setup`?

Comment: Is this available in the metadata API? If so you could use ANT or Eclipse.

Comment: @MikeChale, yes this is available in the metadata API, `<enableReports>true</enableReports>`. I was wondering how I should utilize the metadata API to enable this in all my 100+ `.object` files in Eclipse?

Comment: @SumanKrishnaSaha I fear it will be manual .If something fancy then a java program on top of metadata API and program to update metadata API of sfdc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Reporting disabled* can either be represented as `<enableReports>true</enableReports>`, or no `<enableReports>` tag at all.

Therefore, to enable reporting for all objects:

1. Use Eclipse to download metadata for all objects which reporting needs to be enabled for.
2. Run a Global Replace in the objects folder, and replace all occurrences of `<enableReports>true</enableReports>` to blank value.
3. Again, run a Global Replace in the objects folder, and replace all occurrences of `<enableReports>false</enableReports>` to blank value.
4. Yet again, run a Global Replace in the objects folder, and replace all occurences of `</CustomObject>` with `<enableReports>true</enableReports></CustomObject>`.
5. Save to server.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably:

1. Use Eclipse to download the metadata for each object
2. Run a search and replace on all of the files to switch `false` to `true`
3. Use Eclipse to upload the updated metadata

Comment: you might need to do a search and replace in notepad++ via regular expressions

Comment: @mike In case of false there are chances that tag itself is absent.Its not all about replacing from false to true

Comment: And @Suman's answer addresses that oversight. Thanks for catching that.